# Continuity of a function defined as the limit of another function

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to prove that if the limit of f always exists then the function g defined as the limit of f, is continuous.

I think that because the limit of f always exists then f has to be continuous but I'm not certain.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: In this case $f=g$ and you're done.

Comment: Why is that so?

Comment: Your condition is indeed crucial. Think of a step function. Outside the stepping point $a$ it can be such a limit but not in $a$.

Comment: @GitGud Consider $$f(x)=\begin{cases} x & x\ne0 \\ 10000 & x=0\end{cases}$$ Then $f\ne g$, $f$ not continuous, but $g$ is continuous.

Comment: @Marc You're right in a sense. But wrong in another. More precisely some authors say that $\lim \limits_0(f)$ does not exist in this particular example. **Edit:** And of course this problem is only warranted if the definition of limit is not the one which says that $\lim \limits_0(f)$ doesn't exist.

Comment: @GitGud Possibly, but most definitions (including the definition I prefer to use) do not attempt to describe the behaviour of $f$ at the precise point the limit is being evaluated, merely on every punctured neighbourhood around that point. Of course, you can have a different interpretation of the meaning of "limit" than I do, but in that case the question becomes incredibly trivial, and I do not believe that it is the answer expected by whoever assigned this question.

Comment: @Marc As is implied in the edit to my previous comment, I agree.

Answer (score 1):

We assume that limits are supposed to be defined in some way similar to [the definition given here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#Functions_on_the_real_line). Then it's not necessary for $f$ to be continuous for it to have a limit for every $x$. The function
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x&x\ne0\\10000&x=0\end{cases}$$
is discontinuous at $x=0$, but it has a limit there, namely $$\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=0$$
When this happens, we say that the discontinuity at $x=0$ is *removable*. Then
$$g(x):=\lim_{t\to x}f(t)$$
is the function that "removes" all such discontinuities. In order to show that $g$ is in fact continuous, we merely need to show that $g$ has a limit at every $x$ and that the value of $g$ at every point agrees with its limit there. But it's in fact obvious that
$$\lim_{t\to x}g(t)=\lim_{t\to x}f(t)$$
by a trivial $\epsilon,\delta$ argument if necessary. Hence we conclude that $g$ is in fact a continuous function.